# How to fix SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is the code:

```
def get_technical_indicators(stock_data):
    """Gets technical indicators for the most recent day."""

    # Short and Long Moving Averages
    stock_data.loc[:, 'Short_MA'] = stock_data['Close'].rolling(window=5).mean() 
    stock_data.loc[:, 'Long_MA'] = stock_data['Close'].rolling(window=8).mean()
    
    # Rolling Correlation between Short and Long MA
    stock_data.loc[:, 'Correlation'] = stock_data['Short_MA'].corr(stock_data['Long_MA'])

...

return stock_data
stock_data = get_technical_indicators(stock_data)
stock_data = stock_data.dropna()
```

the warning is:

```
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  stock_data.loc[:, 'Long_MA'] = stock_data['Close'].rolling(window=8).mean()
c:\Users\anuj_\500 days final.py:61: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  stock_data.loc[:, 'Correlation'] = stock_data['Short_MA'].corr(stock_data['Long_MA'])
c:\Users\anuj_\500 days final.py:72: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I tried using the .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead so I changed the code from:

```
stock_data['Short_MA'] = stock_data['Close'].rolling(window=5).mean(),
```

to what is above:

```
stock_data.loc[:, 'Short_MA'] = stock_data['Close'].rolling(window=5).mean()
```

I get the warning with both lines of code.